# Css Help needed to style a <span>

Tags: css

This is my code that I am stuck with and **I can not alter or change it**.

```
<p>
    <span class="small">
        <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
        <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
        <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
        <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
        <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
    </span>
    <em></em>
</p>
```

How do I style each individual star.gif so I can assign a different position for each gif.

I was thinking about the span:first-child route but my css skills are limited.

Comment: Give each image a class.  So for example, you'd add `class="class1"` to the first image tag, then add `class="class2"` and so on.  Then style them in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.  Considering you wrote that you cannot alter any of the existing html, the best way would be using the child selector.  In the example I used Fixed positioning, however you could also use relative if you wish. Example code below, within the CSS we are assigning nth-child(**1**) to each image (the number selects which child it will control).

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .small img:nth-child(1) {
            position:fixed;
            top:20px;
            left:220px;
        }
        .small img:nth-child(2) {
            position:fixed;
            top:20px;
            left:50px;
        }
        .small img:nth-child(3) {
            position:fixed;
            top:40px;
            left:20px;
        }
        .small img:nth-child(4) {
            position:fixed;
            top:120px;
            left:50px;
        }
        .small img:nth-child(5) {
            position:fixed;
            top:50px;
            left:70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <span class="small">
            <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
            <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
            <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
            <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
            <img border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
        </span>
        <em></em>
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.small img:nth-child(4) {
  // selects the 4th image
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KaeLG/)

Further reading: [CSS Tricks - How nth-child Works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Answer (score -2):

It is very simple, just do:

```
<p>
<span class="small">
<img style = "CSS HERE" border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
<img style = "CSS HERE" border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
<img style = "CSS HERE" border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
<img style = "CSS HERE" border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
<img style = "CSS HERE" border="0" alt="star" src="http://islandthrills.com/jomres/images/star.gif">
</span>
<em></em>
</p>
```

Comment: Inline CSS is not preferred, unless of course you're coding HTML emails.  You should separate your CSS and markup as much as possible.